# How to find a power series for a given function?

Tags: calculus, power-series

For homework I was asked to derive a power series for the function $e^{2x}-\frac{1}{x}$ centered at x=1 and I'm honestly clueless as to how to do it. I tried writing out the derivatives and I couldn't figure out a pattern. I'm not really sure how to do power series, so anything helps! My teacher doesn't go very into depth. Do I use Taylor/Maclaurin series to help me find it?

Comment: Do you mean $e^{2x}-\frac1x$?

Comment: yes, sorry about the formatting.

Comment: lt is not possible to include 1/x term in power series!

Comment: I think you have to recheck your question!

Comment: oh wow. that is what it says in the textbook. what should i do?

Comment: Oh, around 1 it is possible! I thought it's around 0. But you now edited.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, this function has Laurent Series at point $x = 0$, namely,
$$e^{2x}-\frac{1}{x}=\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\frac{2^{n}x^{n}}{n!}-\frac{1}{x},$$
its convergent region should be $(-\infty,0)\cup (0,\infty)$, and is very easy to prove.

However, if you want to derive power series for it, let us try to expand this function at point $x=1$.

Since $(e^{2x})^{(n)}=2^{n}e^{2x}$,
$$e^{2x}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{2^{n}e^2(x-1)^n}{n!},$$
its convergent region should be $(-\infty,\infty)$.

Regarding $\frac{1}{x}$, since $\frac{1}{x}=\frac{1}{1-(1-x)}$,
$$\frac{1}{x}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(1-x)^{n}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n (x-1)^n,$$
its convergent region should be $(0,2)$.

Thus,
$$e^{2x}-\frac{1}{x}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{2^{n}e^2(x-1)^n}{n!}-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n (x-1)^n,$$
its convergent region should only be $(0,2)$.

I am not quite sure it is what you mean. Hope so.

Comment: But op asked for a power series!

Comment: Right, I answered it after the Laurent Series.

Comment: Would the 1/x series not be subtracted from e^2x series?

Comment: Sorry, that's a typo. Have fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

To get a power series at $x=1$ I would write $x=1+y$ and expand in powers of $y$. In
your example,
$$e^{2x}-\frac{1}x=e^2e^{2y}-\frac1{1+y}=e^2\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{2^n}{n!}y^n
-\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^ny^n$$
whenever $|y|<1$.
If you like, you can substitute $x-1$ for $y$.

Answer (score 1):

A [Laurent series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurent_series), as opposed to a Taylor series, allows positive and negative exponents.  If that is the type of series you are after, expand $e^{2x}$ in a Taylor series, which you presumably know how to do, and subtract $\frac 1x$ and you are done.  If you want a series in positive powers of $x$ you can't do that around $0$, but you can do that around any other point in the complex plane.  The resulting series will converge in a circle with a radius of the distance from your point to the origin.